# Equivalence relation for ,  ∈ Z,  if and only if 5|( − ).

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We define a relation  on the integers as follows: For all integers ,  ∈ Z,  if and only if 5|( − ).

1. How do I prove that  is an equivalence relation.
2. How do I give a description of the equivalence class [2] and find at least 3 members of this equivalence class?

Comment: 1. Show that it is *reflexive*, *symmetric* and *transitive*.

Comment: As a further push in understanding this problem... you should be **very** familiar with the equivalence relation where it was instead $xRy$ if and only if $10\mid (x-y)$.  That equivalence relation is more commonly described as "*Ending in the same digit*"